# Can the product attribute "size" be used for other items?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

We've been having issues for some time with what product attributes would be considered "correct" in relation to our products being sold. We sell a variety of pop culture collectibles and memorabilia. Google Products makes no mention of using the "size" attribute in relation to anything but clothing. However, this is used readily at marketplaces such as eBay. I would not assume to take this as the correct way, as eBay seems to have their own rules which Google conveniently glosses over due to the vast amounts of money they no doubt receive. But I could be wrong. We've been using the google products attribute "height" (could be an ecrater specific internal attribute as not all attributes offered by google are allowed there), but I've starting to doubt that as well, since it seems to imply shipping dimensions for cost comparison. Perhaps there is no perfect fit, but I would like to know what is considered the "right way" and in what format (e.g. inches, in, or the shortened "quote" symbol) it should be listed, as well as any information related to use of the dimensions attributes.

Comment: I removed your question about page titles because it is not related to the main question you have here.  I also removed the link to your site which is not necessary and the signature you attached which is not allowed. You also need to clarify what "height attribute" are you talking about. Microformat? Some other structure or API feature?